# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, exc-bad-access

i was creating an app that have sliding menu. it reads data from rss using xml parsing and reads data from dashboard using JSon.

my problem is that i got  EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m and in debug area, there is no exception log...

features are works perfectly. but suddenly app crashes with this exception.

am using Xcode 5 with arc.

is this any kind of memory issue. how can i resolve this?

i read some article related to memory management. but that are not much helpful...
pls help me....

Comment: [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Comment: zombie objects are not helpful... my app quit nd shows "app terminated due to memory pressure"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add "Symbolic Breakpoint" and check where is the problem

[This is instruction how to set breakpoint in xCode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html)

Comment: i did. as i commented for some answer below, the problem occurred at different places....

Comment: Symbolic breakpoints are an important feature in debugging, because you can reach points, where you cannot set a usual breakpoint. you also should set the exeption breakpoint for all exeptions

Answer (score -1):

Too little information to solve problems
This could be because:
The pointer used to point to memory that was ok, but its chunk was deallocated.
The pointer is corrupt.

Read [this](http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access).

Comment: i know details i provided is less. its because the exception occurred at different places. so i dont know which one should i give. am sorry about that...